# How to format(dd/mm/yyyy) the sharepoint date field while retrieving and dispalying in textbox

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I am reading sharepoint list item using java script and displaying content inside the content
editor webpart text box, the date value in text box appears like below:

```
2014-09-06 00:00:00
```

I want to display the above date value like below:

```
09/06/2014  (dd/mm/yyyy)
```

How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById("txtClaimDate").value=rows[0].getAttribute('ows_Claim_x0020_Date');
```

Comment: You can use [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to create a formatted string.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply transform the date with javascript Date

```
var selectedDate = rows[0].getAttribute('ows_Claim_x0020_Date');
var check = function(n) {return (Number(n) < 10) ? "0" + n : String(n);}; //Used for leading 0
var date = new Date(selectedDate);
var delimiter = "/";
var newDate = check(date.getMonth() + 1) + delimiter + check(date.getDate()) + delimiter + date.getFullYear();

document.getElementById("txtClaimDate").value = newDate;
```

Comment: This code will produce "9/6/2014" and not "09/06/2014" (i.e. you'll have to add the leading zeros).

Answer (score 0):

You can just parse the date components and put them back together as you wish:

```
var dateString = rows[0].getAttribute('ows_Claim_x0020_Date');
var components = dateString.split(/\D/); // Split on non-decimal characters
document.getElementById("txtClaimDate").value =
    components[1] + "/" + components[2] + "/" + components[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SharePoint 2013 dynamically loads a script called MicrosoftAjax.js which prototypes a function called **format** on date objects. I'm guessing the documentation is similar to that of the [C# version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx), but I can't say for sure.